# Proving recurrence relation exists in Big-O

Tags: elementary-set-theory, induction, recurrence-relations

The recurrence relation **a** is defined as follows. Sow that **a** $\in$ O $(2^n)$.

$a_0$ = 1

$a_1$ = 2

$a_n$ = 1 + $a_{n-1}$ + $a_{n-2}$

I am having trouble proving that this recurrence is true. I tried using n = 2 as the base case. $a_2$ = 4 once I replace the 2 for the n in the last condition. I then show that $2^2$ is also = 4 thus proving that a $\in$ O $(2^n)$. My only issue is that when I try using 3 the the answer to $a_3$ = 7 and $(2^3)$ = 8. Am I approaching this prove correctly? I also know for a fact that this recurrence is an increasing.

Comment: For $a_n\in O(2^n)$ you don't need $a_n=2^n$ but rather $a_n\le C 2^n$. Using induction here is straightforward. Also, you could use that (but this is overkill) $$a_n = 2 F_n + L_n -1,$$ where $F_n$ is the $n$th Fibonacci number and $L_n$ is the $n$th Lucas number (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2251645/how-many-sequences-out-of-0-1-in-length-n-exists-such-that-the-sub-sequence-11))

Comment: So just for a clear understanding.  All i have to show is that an < C 2^n ? All that why doing induction.  Or was that the paet you said was overkill?

Comment: overkill - if you use Lucas/Fibonacci number expression since you can easily prove this by induction. All you need to do is to take C=1 from the example above and n starting 3, in other words, for all $n \ge 3$ prove that $a_n < 2^n$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We'll show $a_n \le 2^n$ for all $n \ge 0$.

The base case is clear since $a_0 = 1 = 2^0$ and $a_1 = 2 = 2^1$.

Assume that for some $n \ge 1$ we have $a_k \le 2^k$ for all $k=0,1,\ldots, n$. We wish to show that $a_{n+1} \le 2^{n+1}$.

We have
$$a_{n+1} = 1+a_n + a_{n-1} \le 1+2^n+2^{n-1} \le 2^{n-1}+2^n+2^{n-1} = 2^{n}+2^n = 2^{n+1}$$
which completes the proof.